Equivalence of higher categories
I have seen the notion of bicategories and tricategories; they are weak 2 and 3-categories. Is there any relation between weak n-categories and ($\infty$,n) categories? I would like to know.
Thanks.

There are indeed two kinds of approaches to higher categories:

On the one hand, we can define weak $n$-categories: there is the approach of Batanin  and of Grothendieck: define what it means to have a notion o $i$-cell for all $i\leq n$ (where is an ordinal $\leq\omega$) as well as composition laws satisfying associativity and unitality up to equivalence in a coherent way (i.e. the coherences should also be specified as laws). These two approaches are actually rather close to each other; see Ara's thesis (2010).
On the other hand, there are notions of $(\infty,n)$-categories: these are defined axiomatically through the theory of $(\infty,1)$-categories by the work of  Barwick Schommer-Pries. However, there are plenty of putative models of $(\infty,n)$-categories, and proving that each of them is indeed a model can be challenging. A standard model is obtained through iterated complete Segal spaces. Proving that $\Theta_n$-spaces form a model is a theorem of Bergner and Rezk (2014) - with $\Theta_n$ Joyal's category of $n$-level trees. That presheaves of sets on $\Theta_n$ also form a model is a result of Ara, which can be seen as a higher analog of Joyal's quasi-categories as models of $(\infty,1)$-categories. There is also the Segal-category approach worked out by Simpson and his students. Finally there is the model à la Verity: complicial sets. This one has resisted much more: for $(\infty,2)$-categories, the comparison is a theorem of Gagna, Harpaz, and Lanari (2019), and the general case is due Loubaton (2022), partially building on the work of Rovelli and Ozornova. New models are also produced by Tim Campion (2023), in order to be able to construct rather non-trivial operators such as Gray tensor products.

Proving that weak $n$-categories à la Batanin-Grothendieck form a model of $(n,n)$-categories is a wide open problem. This subsumes Grothendieck's original homotopy hypothesis (stating that weak $\omega$-groupoids form a model of homotopy types, i.e. of $(\infty,0)$-categories), formulated in Pursuing stacks and open problem since 1983. There are partial results in low dimension: $(2,2)$-categories can be rectified into strict $2$-categories and weak $2$-categories (aka bicategories) can also be rectified into strict $2$-categories. From dimension $3$ on, we cannot rectify anymore and this becomes much more tricky. Henry and Lanari have shown that one can still compare weak $3$-groupoids and $3$-truncated homotopy types (2019). Their work suggests a road map towards harnessing weak $n$-groupoids for all $n$, but there is still some work to be done. What makes things difficult is that, so far, no one seems to be able to define a homotopy theory of weak $n$-categories in a satisfying way.

These links are really helpful! Thank you.

Batanin has proposed a definition of weak $\infty$-category in

Monoidal Globular Categories As a Natural Environment for the Theory of Weak $n$-Categories

which serves to model weak $n$-categories, although if I remember correctly there is still come controversy around this definition. Perhaps someone more up-to-date on things can fill us in.
